# Adding a JAR file to Python Script

Tags: python, hadoop, jar, apache-pig

I am trying to use a JAR file and import its functionality into my python script. The jar file is located in the same directory as my python script and pig script

**script.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/hadoop/scripts/jyson-1.0.2.jar')
from com.xhaus.jyson import JysonCodec as json

@outputSchema('output_field_name:chararray')
def get_team(arg0):
    return json.loads(arg0)
```

**script.pig**

```
register 'script.py' using jython as script_udf;

a = LOAD 'data.json' USING PigStorage('*') as (line:chararray);
teams = FOREACH a GENERATE script_udf.get_team(line);
dump teams;
```

It is a very simple UDF that I am trying to use, but for some reason I always get an error saying "No module named xhaus". Here are all the classes in that jar.

```
$ jar tf jyson-1.0.2.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/xhaus/
com/xhaus/jyson/
com/xhaus/jyson/JSONDecodeError.class
com/xhaus/jyson/JSONEncodeError.class
com/xhaus/jyson/JSONError.class
com/xhaus/jyson/JysonCodec.class
com/xhaus/jyson/JysonDecoder.class
com/xhaus/jyson/JysonEncoder.class
```

So xhaus exists in the jar, but for some reason this is not being picked up. When I look at a few tutorials, they are able to run these scripts fine. I might be missing a silly detail, please help.

**EDIT:**

This script is executed by pig. So the pig script calls the python script. And the python script uses the JysonCodec class.

```
pig script.pig
```

Comment: Are you running this in Python or Jython?

Comment: I have made the edit to let you know how the script is being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are running this script in pig map reduce mode you need to make the jar available at the job runtime. On the top of your pig script you need to add the following line

```
REGISTER /home/hadoop/scripts/jyson-1.0.2.jar;
```

Then you need to comment out `sys.path.append('/home/hadoop/scripts/jyson-1.0.2.jar')`
from your udf script. The classes from the jar will already be available to the udf since you have registered that with the pig script. So need to change `sys.path`

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey Sayan, what is "pig in mapreduce mode". I am simply running the script using "pig script.pig"

Comment: `map reduce` mode is when you are running it on top of Hadoop. I think in your case it's by default. So 'pig script.pig' should work. The reason you need to register the jar is you need to make the jar available to distributed cache just as your are registering the python script